What is the name of this french movie?
Many years ago, I have looked a french movie where the main characters were cleaning glasses, then they became hostage in a building.
I don't remember the title of this movie. 
Who can help me to find this title?

by glasses, do you mean the kind people wear to help them see, or what people drink out of?

The french title of this movie may be : La tour Montparnasse infernale.

Thanks you for your answer. Phanet for the original french title and Ankit Sharma for the complementary informations

Could it be Don't Die Too hard! Original titled La tour Montparnasse infernale 
From the Description on IMDB - "Eric and Ramzy are working as window washers at the Montparnasse skyscraper in Paris. Thinking that he has a date set up with beautiful executive Marie-Joelle (who in reality hates his guts), Ramzy stays at work late while Eric hangs around with him. As a result, the pair witness a gang of terrorists seize the tower and take its late-night occupants (including Marie- Joelle) hostage. Knowing that only they can save the day, Eric and Ramzy swing into action."
